# IE9 - Javascript suddenly went crazy

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

This morning, IE9 suddenly started acting flakey, specifically on Javascript-heavy sites.

In an OWA site I use regularly, I can't expand or collapse groups, and the preview pane never updates. On a website I'm developing, all jQuery calls now fail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think folks can help (other than wild guesses) without either a link to the site or a copy of the relevant code that isn't working.

Comment: A link to an OWA (Microsoft Outlook Web Access) site? Everything works in every other browser. I'm not asking for help with my application, as it's not specific to that app.

Comment: I was asking for a link to the website you're developing or the relevant code from that site.  If this is happening in multiple sites that used to work, then I'd suggest you check our own IE9 configuration.  Make sure it's not set to IE7 compatibility mode or something like that.  And, if nothing else works, try restarting your computer in case IE9 got somehow wedged.

Comment: Understood, but since it's not localized to one app, and since I'm pretty sure Microsoft hasn't made any changes to OWA in the past 24 hours, it's got to be localized to IE. I've rebooted, cleared cache, etc, with no effect.

Comment: Try IE9 on another computer to isolate whether it's your specific computer or not.

Comment: Reset IE9, Internet Options > Advanced Tab > reset button

Comment: @Moab what does Java have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset IE9

Internet Options > Advanced Tab > Reset button.

[image]